# how to hide local variables

Tags: c++, coding-style

In my code, sometimes there's a long function, to avoid messed up the local variables, i would use a pair of braces to embrace the details so the local variables will not be visible to the rest of the code, e.g.:

```
bool pricing_deals()
{
  //prepare deal type lookup table
  vector<DealType> deal_types; // deal type lookup table
  {
    vector<DealType> deal_types_TRF; 
    vector<DealType> deal_types_DCI; 
    ...
    // code that prepare deal_types by merging deal_types_TRF and deal_types_DCI etc
  }
  // from now on deal_types_TRF and deal_types_DCI are invisible

  //prepare ccy pair lookup table
  vector<CcyPair> ccy_pairs; // ccy pair lookup table
  {
    // code that prepare ccy_pairs;
  }
  // from now on local variables preparing ccy_pairs are invisible

  // real computation starts
  ...
}
```

I wonder if this is a good practice, or there are other ways of doing so you would suggeset?

p.s. I prefer not to break it into smaller functions in this case, as the sub-logic is not likely to be reused by others, and refactoring will cause a lot of parameters to be passed over, which would increase the complexity.

Comment: Did you not see the "DO NOT USE!" on the [tag:coding-style] tag?

Comment: It's probably a sign you can break it up into smaller functions.

Comment: i'd rather not refactor to smaller functions, as i updated in the question.

Comment: IMO this is totally fine. Reducing the number of unused local variables is definitely best practice and this IMO is one of the ways to do that. But I will stil add (despite your comment) don't let this be a substitute for functions where functions make sense.

Comment: @Galik any other ways? ps I've posted in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350114/how-to-hide-local-variables

Comment: Functions is the most common way. It *should* be rare that you would have to pass a lot of parameters, but sometimes, you do need to do so. Keep in mind that sometimes this is a sign that you should be passing a lambda function (inside the lambda you can capture the variables rather than pass them as arguments).

Comment: @athos Cross posting is [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/218012)

Comment: Yes, if `deal_types` doesn't change after initialization consider initializing it using a *lambda* expression (instead of your braces) that way you can make it `const`.

Comment: @Justin passing a lambda... preparing the "actor", something like preparing a callback function? mmm.. never do this before, good idea!

Comment: Please, [don't cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/2988).

Comment: See also [Are “Is it a good practice…?” questions off topic or opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296546/2988) and [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/2988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good practice under some circumstances, if you can't split the function into multiple smaller functions, but you must be aware that when a local variable goes out of scope its destructor is called which may or may be not a problem, for example if you suppose something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  using namespace std;

  vector<string>::const_iterator it;

  {
    const vector<string> data = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
    it = data.begin();
  }

  cout << *it << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Then here you store a `const_iterator` to a `vector` which is released when the scope is closed so you get undefined behavior. This doesn't mean your solution is not a good solution, it just means that you must take into account any specific drawback.

This is also good if you need to allocate many resources in multiple parts of a function so that you can allocate and release them gradually without any need of a memory spike.

Comment: good reminder to be awared of!